# On characterizing modules that don't annihilate any module under tensor product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, flatness

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ an $R$-module. Then under what condition can we deduce that for any nonzero $R$-module $N$, $M\otimes_RN\neq0$?

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.  If $M$ is a flat $R$-module, then what you claim is true ($M \otimes_R N \neq 0$ whenever $N \neq 0$) if and only if $M$ is faithfully flat.  Note that all projective modules are flat, but they don't have to be faithfully flat.

But the results are very nice when your ring is local.  If $R$ is a local ring, then $M$ is free $\iff$ $M$ is projective. If $M$ is finitely generated, or if the unique maximal ideal of $R$ is nilpotent, then free/projective/flat/faithfully flat are all equivalent.

This last thing I mentioned is less well known, so let me give a proof.  Suppose $M$ is flat, $(R,\mathfrak m)$ is local, and $\mathfrak m^N = 0$ for some $N$.  One can show using the '[equational criterion for flatness](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HK)' that a set of elements $x_1, ... , x_n \in M$ is linearly independent over $R$ *if and only if* the images $x_1 + \mathfrak m M, ... , x_n + \mathfrak m M$ in $M/\mathfrak m M$ are linearly independent over $R/\mathfrak m$.

It follows that a basis $x_i + \mathfrak m$ for $M/\mathfrak m M$ over $R/\mathfrak m$ lifts to a linearly independent set $x_i$  in $M$ over $R$.  Letting $N = \sum\limits_i Rx_i$, you have $$M = N + \mathfrak m M = N + \mathfrak m(N + \mathfrak m M) = N + \mathfrak m^2 M$$ $$ = N + \mathfrak m^3 M = \cdots = N + \mathfrak m^N M = N + 0$$ so $M$ is free.  Hence $M$ is also faithfully flat and projective.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I apologize for my mistake. Projectiveness is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: I think you provided a very decent idea, to reduce to the local case, since the property I concerned is certainly local.

Comment: +1 for *"This last thing I mentioned"*